# Python: count if items in a row appears in previous rows together

Tags: python, count, row

I'm having a CSV file and when I read it in python, it looks like this:

```
Column A       B     C
['2002.09.11', 'a', 'b']
['2002.09.11', '', 'b,c']
['2002.09.19', 'd', 'e']
['2002.10.02', 'a,b', 'c']
```

I want to add a column that counts as 1 if any two elements in the last two columns appear together in previous rows. (rows are sorted by time order) It will look like this:

```
Column A       B     C     D
['2002.09.11', 'a', 'b',   0] 
['2002.09.11', '', 'b,c',  0]
['2002.09.19', 'd', 'e',   0]
['2002.10.02', 'a,b', 'c', 1]
```

For better understanding, elements in column B, C (such as 'a', 'b'...) are the names of people and I want to see if they have an experience of working together before.

How can I do this? I'm new to python (and any other programming languages) and just don't have any idea. I'll appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd keep a list of "previously seen sets" and check for intersection size as I go.  I.e, assuming the headers aren't actually there and those square brackets are phantoms (easy to fix the former assumption if broken -- read and write back the first line "blind" if you know it's headers; if the second assumption's broken the file's **not** a valid CSV...:-)...:

```
seen_sets = []
to_write = []

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as fin:
    r = csv.reader(fin)
    for row in r:
        newset = set(r[1].split(',')).union(r[2].split(','))
        prev = any(len(s.intersection(newset)) > 1 for s in seen_sets)
        seen_sets.append(newset)
        row.append('1' if prev else '0')
        to_write.append(row)

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as fou:
    w = csv.writer(fou)
    w.writerows(to_write)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I replaced r[1] with row[1] and had to add .difference(['']) to the same line to avoid count a blank. Overall, it works well. Thanks for your help